# Aerospike: Using asinfo tool to get Mesh Node IPs, Add new mesh node and remove existing mesh node

Tags: aerospike

I am running Aerospike Cluster in mesh mode with 3 nodes and I want to update it dynamically(i.e. without rebooting cluster nodes).

Using "asinfo" tool I want to:

1. Get existing mesh IP addresses in aeorspike.conf of any Aerospike
   node
2. Add new mesh node IP using "asinfo" to aerospike.conf
3. Remove mesh node IP using asinfo

I tried with tip command for point(2), but it did not work:

```
$asinfo -v "tip:host=192.168.0.81;port=3002”
```

I did not found any spefic info here:
http://www.aerospike.com/docs/tools/asinfo

Can you please share info about this ?

```
root@XYZ:/# asinfo -v 'tip:host=9.0.1.131;port=3002'
~~~ -v tip:host = 9.0.1.131 ~~~
Do not understand '=' in '-v tip:host = 9.0.1.131'
~~~ = 3002 --no_node_name ~~~
ERR: Do not understand 'port = 3002 --no_node_name'
```

This might be BUG in Aerospike build 3.11.0.2 as same command seems to be working in older build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating based on the latest info provided:

It looks like the latest asinfo release broke some commands. Those should be fixed in the next release.

A work around would be to, as you did, get the asinfo binary from the previous tools release. I also think that running the command from within the asadm shell should work as well, but haven't verified it.

Original answer before realizing the issue brought up was different: "The tip command will dynamically update the list of nodes the cluster initiate heartbeats against. It will not change the 'on file' configuration, though. The on file configuration would have to be changed manually."